# Trouble comparing two variables in a while loop

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a hangman game to practice python. I have run into a issue when trying to make if statement to check if the person has guessed all the words and announce that the player has won. I am sure it is a easy fix and I am overlooking something, but I have looked at it for a while now. Someone please explain to me, thanks.

error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Aleksander/PycharmProjects/hangman/main.py", line 36, in 
if Blanks_string == secretWord:
NameError: name 'Blanks_string' is not defined

code:

```
from hangman_pics import HANGMAN_PICS


def replaceBlanks():
    WordIndex = secretWord.find(userIn)

    Blanks[WordIndex] = userIn
    global Blanks_string
    Blanks_string = "".join(Blanks)
    print(Blanks_string)



secretWord = "Python"
secretWord = secretWord.lower()

missed_letters = []

attempt_count = 0
attempt_limit = 6


numBlanks = ("_" * len(secretWord))
print("H A N G M A N")
print(HANGMAN_PICS[attempt_count])
print(numBlanks)

Blanks = list(numBlanks)

userIn = input("Guess a letter from the word: ")
userIn = userIn.lower()

while attempt_count != attempt_limit:

    if Blanks_string == secretWord:
        print("You win!")

    print(userIn)

    if userIn in Blanks_string:
        print("You have already entered that letter")
        continue


    if userIn not in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
        print("Enter a character from the alphabet, a-z")
        continue


    if userIn in secretWord:
        replaceBlanks()

    else:
        attempt_count += 1
        print(userIn + " is not in the word")
        print ("Attempts left: " + (str(attempt_limit - attempt_count)))
        print(HANGMAN_PICS[attempt_count])
        missed_letters.append()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `Blanks_string` in a place python doesn't recognize it.

The reason is that you declared it inside the function `replaceBlanks()`

I recommend you reading about **Python's Scope**: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp

When using `global` you need to declare the variable on the outer scope, and when you use `global` it 'tells' the interpreter to change the outer scope variable. again, read the tutorial attached.

Comment: I used the global keyword, would that not make it accessible in the global scope then?

Comment: added explanation about global and scope

Comment: I'm still stuck, can't seem to wrap my head arount it. I've red that everyone is saying that global variables are evil and bad. What would be a good alternative. I don't want go get used to bad practices.

Comment: return `Blanks_string` from the function and then run the function like this:
`Blanks_string = replaceBlanks()` or something similar